# Using NVL in PLSQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I created a function which should accept the employee_id as the parameter, and return the total salary earned by the employee. Where should i place NVL function and return zero if the commission percentage is null?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOTAL_SAL (vemp IN employees.employee_id%type)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    vsalary     employees.salary%type;
    vcommission employees.commission_pct%type;

    CURSOR c_employee IS
    SELECT SALARY 
      FROM employees
     WHERE employee_id = vemp;

BEGIN
    OPEN c_employee;
    FETCH c_employee INTO vsalary;
    CLOSE c_employee;

    vsalary := vsalary + vsalary * vcommission;

    RETURN vsalary;

END;
/
```

Comment: The function does not assign any value to `vcommission`. Is commission percentage stored as part of the employee row, and can it be null?

Comment: Official manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you need a cursor? If you pass employee's `ID`, there can be only one (or none) rows returned, unless two (or more) employees share the same `ID` which would be completely wrong.

Therefore, it looks like this to me.

For the following sample data ...

```
SQL> select * from employees where rownum <= 5;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY COMMISSION_PCT
----------- ---------- --------------
       7369        800
       7499       1600              3
       7521       1250              5
       7566       2975
       7654       1250             14
```

... function computes total salary (or returns `NULL` if an invalid ID has been passed to it):

```
SQL> create or replace function total_sal (vemp in employees.employee_id%type)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    -- presuming everyone has initial salary, there's no need
  7    -- to apply NVL to SALARY column's value
  8    select salary * (1 + nvl(commission_pct, 0)/100)
  9      into retval
 10      from employees
 11      where employee_id = vemp;
 12    return retval;
 13  exception
 14    when no_data_found then
 15      return null;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> select e.*, total_sal(employee_id) total
  2  from employees e where rownum <= 5;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY COMMISSION_PCT      TOTAL
----------- ---------- -------------- ----------
       7369        800                       800
       7499       1600              3       1648   --> 3% out of 1600 is 48, so total = 1600 + 48 = 1648
       7521       1250              5     1312,5
       7566       2975                      2975
       7654       1250             14       1425

SQL>
```

For an invalid `ID`:

```
SQL> select total_sal(-1e99) total_sal from dual;

 TOTAL_SAL
----------


SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would use it.

```
cursor c_employee is
select NVL(SALARY, 0)
FROM employees
where employee_id = vemp;
```

For more PLSQL stuff and others, this is a great resource:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer either style;

1. Within the SQL SELECT Statement;

   ```
   CURSOR c_employee IS
   SELECT NVL(salary,0)
     FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = vemp;
   ```

**or**

2. Within the PL/SQL code block

   ```
   vsalary := NVL(vsalary,0) + NVL(vsalary,0) * NVL(vcommission,0);
   ```

   **or**

   ```
   vsalary := vsalary + vsalary * NVL(vcommission,0);
   ```

   provided that the `NVL()` function is already applied within the SELECT statement.

noting that `vcommission` would need the `NVL()` function more than a salary.

*Btw,seems you mean `vemp` as the parameter, while `employee_id` is the column of the table*